# POP3 email integration with Gmail/hotmail

Tags: gmail, email-client, pop3

Actually, I am doubtful about the security for integrating my pop3 email with other public domain such as gmail or hotmail out there.. is it safe to attach pop3 email or my official email id with such domain ? safe is to mean that whether my email content will be monitored by  them and whether this gonna create any privacy issue or not ?
(Thing is now a days Gmail is readily available on mobile devices so, it is easy for me to stay updated rather than to login everytime on my pc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google/hotmail wont intrude into your privacy if you use pop3.

This guide will help you to congifure IMAP/POP of Gmail

> https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665119

Comment: okay... so for now I didn't got any other answer for this question, I will have to accept your answer :) :)